IBM MQ System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm
From windows server we are getting below issue while connecting to IBM MQ, this issue we faced after upgrading GPO with new cipher suites, where as same has been done on another server and from other server we are able to connect with strong cipher. I have checked the configuration which are same in both servers and there is no change in code.
0000041C 03:11:04.429151   1160.4      System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm
   at System.Net.SSPIWrapper.AcquireCredentialsHandle(SSPIInterface SecModule, String package, CredentialUse intent, SecureCredential scc)
   at System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.AcquireCredentialsHandle(CredentialUse credUsage, SecureCredential& secureCredential)
   at System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.AcquireClientCredentials(Byte[]& thumbPrint)
   at System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.GenerateToken(Byte[] input, Int32 offset, Int32 count, Byte[]& output)
   at System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.NextMessage(Byte[] incoming, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(String targetHost, X509CertificateCollection clientCertificates, SslProtocols enabledSslProtocols, Boolean checkCertificateRevocation)
   at IBM.WMQ.Nmqi.MQEncryptedSocket.MakeSecuredConnection()


You say that you upgraded GPO with new cipher suites. Was that an addition of cipher suites or did you change the list completely?
The list of Ciphersuites an IBM MQ queue manager supports are listed here: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.3?topic=messages-enabling-cipherspecs you need to ensure that at least one of those ciphersuites are available in your GPO environment.
